# process from scratch using wurst

Tags: brightway

I am redefining the electricity market in a region and some of the activities supplying the electricity are created from scratch (a combination of technosphere and biosphere flows).

I was now trying to do it with wurst (so the relinking does its magic and affects all processes consuming electricity). however, I am having some trouble.

Do I need to extract the biosphere database to add biosphere flows? I have the impressions *extract_brightway2_databases* is not intended to be used that way. For instance I think the compartment info is lost (or I do not find it).

If I want to use processes from scratch. should I 1) define it a separate database (like [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2/raw/default/notebooks/Activities%20and%20exchanges.ipynb)) 2) merge it with my background database 3) read it with wurst ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your individual datasets in BW2, generating separate databases.

Then, in Wurst you can extract all your newly created database objects, like so:

`from wurst import *
db_nabla = extract_brightway2_databases(['ecoinvent consequential', 'electric board', 'nabla_maple_syrup_extraction_plant, 'massive_hydro'])`

Once extracted, you have everything in a big dictionary. You can create different copies of your new datasets doing the modifications you want.

To build your mixes, you can point to the required datasets from any databases contained in `db_nabla`, using functions from Wurst: `get_many(db, ...)` or `get_one(db, ...)`

Comment: okk, I guess that means wurst is not thought to create new processes, just to modify them.